# Use cordova with existing webapp

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I want to display dynamically generated html from my flask server in cordova.  I searched up the answer and a lot of them recommend to do something like this in the index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function onBodyLoad(){     
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     }
     function onDeviceReady(){
         window.location.href = <your_remote_url>
     }
}
</script>
```

Sadly this does not work and opens the page in the device's native browser.  Is there another work around?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use cordova in app browser.

This will open the page in the app itself.

install

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

how to use check..

```
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#sample
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling uncomfortable installing another plugin, 
please try iframe to display a webview within the app. 
Something like,

```
<div style="height: 100vh;">
  <iframe src="http://google.com" style="border: 0; height: 100vh; width:100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to use the plugin mentioned above (resources, speed, compatibility)?

Comment: No offence. But just based on my experience, it's always good to have fewer plugins because of performance and compatibility, permissions, etc. The same idea goes go javascripts too. (obviously)